How do I extract the dataframe from an edited Table in a GUI?

What strategy should I use to have a GUI that selects a dataset (API Get) storing it in a Frame, and allows one to edit the dataframe to update the API (API patch)? I originally created the GUI and functions to be separate. Everything worked, but I was not able to capture changes to the dataframe, if one edited the dataframe in the Table.
A colleague suggested I needed to create a Class to capture the state of the dataframe.

create a class for the GUI.
a. create a canvas.
b. create a frame inside the canvas for the pandastable Table.

The GUI has labels and buttons to filter the API Get request.
a. labels/textboxes for Project and Name filters.
b. button to select which API Get request to run.


I am starting to get confused.
Should the button to select the dataset be a function command, or a Class method?


import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
import pandas as pd
from pandastable import Table, TableModel, config
from drofus import Projects, Items #, RoomTemplates, Items, Rooms

WINDOW_WIDTH = 940
WINDOW_HEIGHT = 500
HEADER_HEIGHT = round(WINDOW_HEIGHT/15, 0)
HEADER_FONT = int(round(WINDOW_HEIGHT/20, 0))
BUTTON_WIDTH = 20

PROJECT = 'Projects'
ITEM = "Items"

def get_project(filter: str) -> pd.DataFrame:
    module = Projects()

    # dRofus API request
    projects = module.filter(filter_api=filter)
    with pd.option_context("future.no_silent_downcasting", True):
        projects.infer_objects(copy=False).drop(projects.iloc[:, 10:19], inplace=True, axis=1)
        projects_revised = projects.rename(columns={'Template Name':'Project'})
        return projects_revised

def get_item():
    pass



class Drofus(Frame):
    """Basic test frame for the table"""

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        self.parent = parent
        Frame.__init__(self)
        self.main = self.master
        self.main.geometry(f"{WINDOW_WIDTH}x{WINDOW_HEIGHT}")
        self.main.title('Design Standards Database')
        self.canvas = Canvas(self.main,
                             width=WINDOW_WIDTH,
                             height=WINDOW_HEIGHT,
                             background='white',
                             borderwidth=0,
                             highlightthickness=0)
        header_id = self.canvas.create_text(WINDOW_WIDTH / 2, HEADER_HEIGHT, text="Welcome",
                                            font=("Arial", HEADER_FONT, "normal"), fill="dimgrey", anchor='s')
        self.canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=4)
        table_frame = Frame(self.main, highlightthickness=5, highlightcolor="orange")
        table_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=40, pady=40)

        df = get_project(filter="None")
        self.table = pt = Table(table_frame,
                                dataframe=df,
                                showtoolbar=False,
                                showstatusbar=True)
        pt.show()

        proj_filter_label = Label(table_frame, text="Project filter")
        proj_filter_label.grid(row=4, column=1, sticky="e")
        name_filter_label = Label(table_frame, text="Name filter")
        name_filter_label.grid(row=5, column=1, sticky="e")

        proj_filter_textbox = Entry(table_frame)
        proj_filter_textbox.grid(row=4, column=2, sticky="w")
        name_filter_textbox = Entry(table_frame)
        name_filter_textbox.grid(row=5, column=2, sticky="w")

        module_options = [PROJECT, ITEM]
        module_variable = StringVar(value=module_options[0])
        module_variable.set("dRofus Module")

        module_dropdown = OptionMenu(table_frame, module_variable, *module_options, command=select_dataset)
        module_dropdown.config(width=BUTTON_WIDTH)
        module_dropdown.grid(row=5, column=3, sticky="w")
        return

def select_dataset(event):
    selected = module_variable.get()

    if select == PROJECT:
        if proj_filter_textbox.get():
            module_filter = proj_filter_textbox.get()
        else:
            module_filter = name_filter_textbox.get()

        get_project(filter=module_filter)

    else:
        module_filter = name_filter_textbox.get()
        get_item()

def main():
    drofus_df = Drofus()
    drofus_df.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()



Please offer some guidance on whether I should continue using the Class, and whether the "dRofus Module" button should be a function or a Class method.
Thank you.

To access the dataframe of Table, use self.table.model.df.  See official document.  Asking whether using a function or a class method is opinion-based question which is not an acceptable question in StackOverflow.
